# QuickSort Algorithm modification

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

The implementation of QuickSort alogorithm is as follows :

// Java program for implementation of QuickSort

```
class QuickSort
{
    /* This function takes last element as pivot,
       places the pivot element at its correct
       position in sorted array, and places all
       smaller (smaller than pivot) to left of
       pivot and all greater elements to right
       of pivot */
    int partition(int arr[], int low, int high)
    {
        int pivot = arr[high]; 
        int i = (low-1); // index of smaller element
        for (int j=low; j<high; j++)
        {
            // If current element is smaller than or
            // equal to pivot
            if (arr[j] <= pivot)
            {
                i++;

                // swap arr[i] and arr[j]
                int temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
            }
        }

        // swap arr[i+1] and arr[high] (or pivot)
        int temp = arr[i+1];
        arr[i+1] = arr[high];
        arr[high] = temp;

        return i+1;
    }


    /* The main function that implements QuickSort()
      arr[] --> Array to be sorted,
      low  --> Starting index,
      high  --> Ending index */
    void sort(int arr[], int low, int high)
    {
        if (low < high)
        {
            /* pi is partitioning index, arr[pi] is 
              now at right place */
            int pi = partition(arr, low, high);

            // Recursively sort elements before
            // partition and after partition
            sort(arr, low, pi-1);
            sort(arr, pi+1, high);
        }
    }

    /* A utility function to print array of size n */
    static void printArray(int arr[])
    {
        int n = arr.length;
        for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
            System.out.print(arr[i]+" ");
        System.out.println();
    }

    // Driver program
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int arr[] = {10, 7, 8, 9, 1, 5};
        int n = arr.length;

        QuickSort ob = new QuickSort();
        ob.sort(arr, 0, n-1);

        System.out.println("sorted array");
        printArray(arr);
    }
}
```

If I modify the code and make changes to partition method as mentioned below, will it still be called QuickSort or am I missing something?

```
int partition(int arr[], int low, int high)
 {
     int pivot = arr[high]; 
     int i = (low-1); // index of smaller element
     for (int j=low; j<=high; j++)
     {
         // If current element is smaller than or
         // equal to pivot
         if (arr[j] <= pivot)
         {
             i++;

             // swap arr[i] and arr[j]
             int temp = arr[i];
             arr[i] = arr[j];
             arr[j] = temp;
         }
     }

     // swap arr[i+1] and arr[high] (or pivot)
//     int temp = arr[i+1];
//     arr[i+1] = arr[high];
//     arr[high] = temp;
//
//     return i+1;
     return i;
 }
```

In the above code, I have made changes by modifying the for loop and changing the return statement. Also, I have highlighted the other code. 
I look forward to hearing from the community.

Comment: It's still a Quicksort. Whether it works, or is any better, is another question. I don't see the point of including the pivot element I he outer loop and therefore swapping it with itself, not of returning the wrong value. You seem to be just increasing the amount of work done.

Comment: Can you please elaborate if this algorithm would work after changes. Also will the changes lead to better space and time complexity? How would you make changes to prevent pivot from swapping itself each time. Thanks! @EJP

Comment: Can *you* please elaborate *why* you made these changes. It's a well-known algorithm, and there are many good implementations available. People have been investigating improvements to it for 55 years. You're not likely to just stumble on another one by apparently arbitrary changes like this, which you don't appear to even understand yourself. NB The way to prevent pivot swapping is not to make the changes you made. Surely that is clear?

Comment: Thanks for your help. The change I made is my my own logic. If asked in interview, I would prefer coming with my own solution rather mugging up algorithms. However, since the implementation is not right, I would be reluctant using it during interview. Peace!

Comment: I am unable to make head or tail of any of this. You're not going to get asked in an interview how to improve the QuickSort algorithm, and even if you are you will be expected to come up with something like sorting the smaller partition first, or median-of-3 partioning or any of the other well-known variations. The point of your question escapes me entirely.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.!